# jquery removeData slow performance

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i've a bootstrap modal window populated with dynamic external content.
I call it with:

```
<a href="modal-detail.php?id=someValue"
   data-toggle="modal" 
   data-target="#modalDetail">Open Modal</a>
```

When i close modal window i remove data with:

```
$("#myModal").on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
});
```

It works but there is latency time when i open same modal with a different parameter (i see old content). 
Do you have any idea to solve my problem?

Comment: `removeData` is synchronous, so as soon as the `hide` callback is triggered, that data is gone. Your mission, Mr. Hunt, should you choose to accept it, is to create an [mcve] so we can see the full picture of what's going on and help you identify where the problem really is.

Answer (score 0):

Use  `.removeData('bs.modal');`  before setting data /content with new parameter and then show modal

*For Example:*

```
$("#myModal").on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    //and then set your data here
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Yo Yo. I use hide.bs.modal instead of shown.bs.modal, but it's the same thing. What do you mean by "set your data here"?
I set my data with a php call in modal link.

Answer (score 0):

**I found the solution!**

```
$(this).removeData("bs.modal").find(".modal-content").empty();
```

I hope it may help someone